# Mean value weighed by inverse distance

Tags: statistics

I want to estimate the value $Z$ for some point $(X, Y)$. I know the values for some points. The situation is illustrated in the following image.

[image]

I know the $Z$ values for points $p_1...p_4$, and I want to estimate $Z$ value for $p$. The value would be calculated as a weighed mean of the four known values. So the value would be

```
Z = (w1 * z1 + w2 * z2 + w3 * z3 + w4 * z4) / 4
```

I want weights to be inversely proportional to the distance ( w1 ~ 1 / d1, w2 ~ 1 / d2 and so on). This means, that the points closest to p will influence the value of Z the most.

Could someone help me to come up with the formula (or weights)?

Answer (score 1):

A working formula seems to be

$$Z = \frac{\frac{1}{d_1} \cdot z_1 + \frac{1}{d_2} \cdot  z_2 + \frac{1}{d_3} \cdot z_3 + \frac{1}{d_4} \cdot z_4}{\frac{1}{d_1} + \frac{1}{d_2} + \frac{1}{d_3} + \frac{1}{d_4}}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).